# Java matrix multiplication: threaded slow than non-threaded in the case of little columns

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I’m testing a dot product program in Java with threaded (according to the number of system cores) and non-threaded options. The (very simple) algorithm divides the first (say A) matrix into as many matrices as cores and performs the dot product with the full B matrix. Once this is done, ‘chunks’ are collected obtaining the resulting matrix. When rows and columns are of a relatively high magnitude (say 20000 rows and 20000 columns) then threaded option works as expected, getting speeds 3.3-3.5 times faster than non-threading option with a standard four cores system.

But for a little number of columns in the first matrix (say, for instance, A[20000][20] multiplied by B[20][20000]) speeds from threaded and non-threaded options roughly equals. And for less columns, execution time under threaded condition is noticeably superior that under non-threaded option. This “equality frontier” varies according to the number of rows.

I understand the problems with overloaded threads system for little matrices, but I can’t fully understand this situation under a little number of columns only (columns in the first matrix factor, rows in the second). If the problem is of the same nature as that of the small matrices, is there a proportion between rows and columns that permits to choose a threaded or a non-threaded algorithm depending on the cases?

Comment: When you’re asking about a problem with your code, you should post a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Erwin. I take note for future asks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating a new thread always costs a (roughly constant) amount of computing time and before your program can benefit from it, the work per thread must take longer than this overhead.
I don't know you code (please post minimal examples in future, like the comment suggested), but you can look at the number of calculations (multiplacation + addition) each thread is evaluating at the equal calculation time. Based on this you should be able to approximate the size of the matrix (probably proportional to the product of side lengths = number of elements) where the multithreading is worth the trouble.

Comment: many thanks for your comment and your time. My question was more conceptual than practical (apologies to all for that), but your answer gives me clues to continue investigating in the number of ops (mult. and adds) of each thread. There is a direct relation between number of elements and thread effectiveness, of course, but when we find a little number of columns in the first factor we are then working with a lot of multiplications and a little number of additions, not to mention the very different output result in product matrix size. Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Isasa I suggest you reuse a thread pool such as the thread pool used by Stream.parallel()

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, Peter. I was trying a more 'classic' solution with threads, but I'll give a chance to Stream API as a newer (well, Java 8, as time goes by...) solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @A.Isasa I find IntStream.range(0, a.length).parallel().etc very useful.